# Finding current quarter of year in PowerShell to append in a filename with format "yyyyqq"

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find current quarter of year in PowerShell to append in a filename with format `yyyyqq`.

I have already got current month and week as below:

```
$WeekYYYYWW = (get-date (Get-Date).AddDays(-7) -UFormat "%Y%V")
$yesterdayMMDDYY=(get-date (get-date).AddDays(-1) -uformat %m%d%Y)
$monthly=(get-date (get-date).AddDays(-1) -uformat %m%Y)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way is:

```
"$(Get-date -f yyyy)$("{0:00}" -f [Math]::ceiling((Get-date -f MM)/3) )"
```

Answer (score 0):

one way is:

```
$yearYYYYQQ = "$(get-date -uformat %Y)$("{0:00}" -f [int]((get-date).month/4) )"
```

Comment: This is the result m getting after using this

QuarterlyRegionalDashboard_Sales_Q_201302

In which the above code is getting value as 201302 as current year followed by quarter

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
$today = Get-Date
$YearYYYYQQ = "{0}{1:d2}" -f ($today.Year, [int][math]::Ceiling($today.Month/3))
```

Comment: This is the result m getting after using this

QuarterlyRegionalDashboard_Sales_Q_201301

In which the above code is getting value as 201301 as current year followed by quarter

Comment: My mistake. The number of the month must be divided by the number of months per quarter, of course, and the result must be rounded *up*, not down.

Answer (score 0):

```
"$([datetime]::Now.Year)$(([math]::Ceiling(([datetime]::Now.Month)/3)).ToString().PadLeft(2,"0"))"
```