# Find Quarter from file having Name and DateTime as File Name using Powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Ok, I am beginer and lost here.

I have a file containing a Name and DateTime as File Name. So I am extracting date in ADATE variable

Sample Name--> 
PN-PN-EAST-% of ABC at the level of DEF in GHI-Quarterly-Exceptions-2017-07-03-08-02-11.xlsx

PN-PN-EAST-% of ABC at the level of DEF in GHI-Monthly-Exceptions-2017-06-02-09-04-14.CSV

```
for /D %%d in ("C:\AA\*") do (
for %%a in ("%%d\*.*") do (SET "FPath=%%~dpa"
Set "FName=%%~na" )  
)
::echo %FPath%/%FName%
::timeout 4

For /F "Tokens=4-9 Delims=-" %%A In ("%FName%") Do (
Set "Freq=%%B"
Set "ADate=%%F%%E%%D"
)
```

Till here it is working as expected(for finding Month)

```
Set "DFormat=ddMMyyyy"

For /F UseBackQ %%A In (
    `Powershell "([datetime]::ParseExact('%ADate%','%DFormat%', [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture)).AddMonths(-1).ToString('MMM-yyyy')"`
) Do Set "DateF=%%A"
```

But Now I want to extract date from file name subtract one month and convert/find quarter for the same

```
For /F UseBackQ %%A In (
    `Powershell "([datetime]::ParseExact('%ADate%','%DFormat%',[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture)).AddQuarter(-1).ToString('M')"`
 ) Do Set "DateF=%%A"
```

Expected- Q1-2017, Q2-2017 etc

Please it is not duplicate of- 
[Finding current quarter of year in PowerShell to append in a filename with format "yyyyqq"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719822/finding-current-quarter-of-year-in-powershell-to-append-in-a-filename-with-forma)

Comment: It would certainly help were you to amend your question by providing **at least one example of the file names** you're parsing. Also, when you state that you're after the quarter, you need to define what you mean by that. My answer provides calendar quarters, if you need fiscal quarters, they are changeable from country to country, so you would need to explain exactly **what criteria determines a fiscal quarter** for your purposes as an amendment to your question too!

Comment: Hi All, I have added Sample File Name in question

Comment: @Compo I am using Calendar quarter, thanks for high lighting this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made some adjustment with my previous implementation and it is working for all months now..

```
([int]([datetime]::ParseExact('%ADate%','%DFormat%',[System‌​.Globalization.Cultu‌​reInfo]::CurrentCult‌​ure)).AddMonths(-1))​.ToString('MM'))"
```

For More Details- [Q3-2017 logic for October is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47027824/q3-2017-logic-for-october-is-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"

for /D %%d in ("%sourcedir%") do (
 for %%a in ("%%d\*-*-*-*.*") do (SET "FPath=%%~dpa"
  Set "FName=%%~na"
  CALL :process 
 )  
)

GOTO :eof

:process

echo %FPath%/%FName%
::timeout 4

For /F "Tokens=4-9 Delims=-" %%A In ("%Fname%") Do (
 Set "Freq=%%B"
 Set "ADate=%%F%%E%%D"
 SET /a qtr=((100%%E %% 100 - 2^) / 3^) + 1
 IF "%%E"=="01" (SET /a qtr=4&SET /a year=%%F - 1) ELSE (SET /a year=%%F)
)
ECHO Q%qtr%-%year%
ECHO %freq%
ECHO %adate%

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I altered the filemask to select only files that fit the pattern provided. You may need to refine this further.

Note that the routine `:process` is executed for *each* matching filename. Any required processing of each individual file needs to be performed in the `:process` routine - you don't mention processing required, so the various extracted and processed elements are displayed via `echo` statements in the `:process` routine.

The additional processing to  extract the quarter of (the month before the date for the file being processed) is to first string the month after the string `100` (I'm assuming your *month* element appears in `%%E`), take the mod-100 of the result, subtract 2 (which yields 0..2 for original Feb-Apr, 3..5 for May-Jul, etc) ; divide the result by 3 and add 1.

January is a special case, so if the month is January, the quarter is 4 and the year is reduced by 1, otherwise the year is (I assume) in `%%F`.

I've no idea what re the PS code is to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you to retrieve the data you need?

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /D %%A In ("AA\*") Do (For %%B In ("%%A\*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*.*") Do (
        For /F "Tokens=5,7-9 Delims=-" %%C In ("%%~nB") Do (Echo %%~fB
            Echo File Path = %%~dpB
            Echo Frequency = %%C
            For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=1-2" %%G In (
                `Powershell "([datetime]::ParseExact('%%D%%E%%F','yyyyMMdd', [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture)).AddMonths(-1).ToString('MM yyyy')"`
            ) Do (Set/A "Quart=(1%%G-101)/3+1"
                Echo Expected  = Q!Quart!-%%H)
            Echo=)))
Pause
```

I have assumed that the date information in the file name is in the format of `yyyy-MM-dd` if that should be `yyyy-dd-MM` change `yyyyMMdd` on line 8 to read `yyyyddMM`

***temporary edit***

Ashu, create this exact script, *QTest.cmd*, and run it:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For %%G In (01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12
) Do (Set/A "Quart=(1%%G-101)/3+1"
    Echo Q!Quart!)
Pause
```

You can see that all twelve months work as expected, so please explain to me why you believe the script cannot read "!"

Comment: I am not player of this, And as you told I do have location of the date and the order of it's date parts but need to subtract few Days/month/Week depending on file. And have got this code from another thread on stackoverflow. May be you can offer more better option. if possible.

Comment: I have updated my answer, based on your now provided file names. _Oh and BTW, you got the code from me!_

Comment: I am using.
        For /F UseBackQ %%A In (
        `Powershell "([datetime]::ParseExact('%ADate%','%DFormat%',[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture)).AddMonths(-1).ToString('MM')"`
    ) Do ( Set /a "FPart1=%%A/3")  It is working for all month except 10 (October Month) Can you please check once.

Comment: What happens when you run my entire script above on the same data set? _I've gone to the effort of helping you with your questions, the least you could do is show me the courtesy of trying it and providing feedback, if not for yourself, for the benefit of the site and future readers_.

Comment: My script is not able to read "!" < Echo Expected = Q!Quart!-%%H > , I am not clear with the reason. So now was using above mention Script, but it is failing only for October.

Comment: I provided as my answer an entire script, with instructions on which part ONLY you can, if my assumption was incorrect, change. Run it against the same data and it should be fine, change it and it may have problems. I cannot guess what you've added, removed or modified so cannot help you unless you **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46461128/edit)** your answer, add the exact script which is failing, verify the source information, and give me a reasonable opportunity to help.

Comment: @Ashu, I have made a **temporary edit**, which I will likely remove again in the near future, it shows only that the results should work fine unless you change things.